# Get-WmiObject throws "Invalid access to memory location."

Tags: powershell, wmi, winpe, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to run the following PowerShell command under WinPE (Version 10.0.10586.0):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
```

But I get this error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6) 
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], BadImageFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Searching Google I only found that the `WinPE-WMI.cab` might be missing. But that isn't the case!

Any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception) might be of help to you.